# Changes in js/html on rails production server requires restart

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails world(1 yr old). I deployed my application on server and later on wanted to change some html and js (js within the same html.erb file). I thought changes would be reflected immediately and restart is not required. But I had to restart server for changes to be reflected on page.

Why is this so? I used to work on .net earlier and their we didn't require to restart server for html/js changes.

**Edit:**
I made changes in app/views/home/index.html.erb. No changes in any files from assets folder.

Comment: Was the app running in production mode with precompiled assets?

Comment: Rails production environments typically don't serve static content from public, your web server would do that. Also, you seem to be asking why Rails and .Net do something differently, the better question would be why do you think they necessarily have to be the same?

Comment: @meagar page is in app/views folder and not in public. I am just curious on understanding the mechanism, even after changing content how the webserver serves the old content?

Comment: Rails loads things off disc once. In development, it will go back to disc each request, but this is purely to make development easier. In production everything is served out of memory for performance reasons. Rails assumes (quite rightly) that you won't be modifying files on disc for a running production app and that you'd happily trade the ability to do so for better throughput.

Answer (score 0):

In order to speed up Rails in production, it enables a lot of caching, the line you're looking for is `config.cache_classes` in your `production.rb` (techincally it's actually `config.action_view.cache_template_loading`, but that [defaults to what `config.cache_caches` is set to](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration)). Disabling this will reload the code between requests, but will also slow down your app considerably.

Comment: I made changes in app/views/home/index.html.erb. No changes in any files from assets folder. I thought precompile is required when you change any file from assets folder.

Comment: That has nothing to do with asset precompilation. Asset precompilation works on JavaScript, CSS, images and other static content served out of app/assets, not on views.

Comment: Sorry about that, misinterpreted where the changes were being made, answer has been updated.